# I would like to make the rendered image an image with an alpha channel

Tags: rendering

When I open the rendered image in Photoshop, I would like it to be an image with a mask (alpha channel).
For example, you can put a mask on a glass window in interior perspective and replace that part with Photoshop.
Does a blender have such a function?

Comment: Maybe you're talking about the Holdout option (in the Object panel > Visibility), also available as node in the Shader Editor?

Comment: ありがとう御座います　マスクを作ることが出来ました

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to make a mask.

Answer (score 0):

Select the object that you want to make alpha transparent and in the *Object panel > Visibility*, enable the *Holdout* option:

[image]